# show that $S_7$ has no subgroup of order 11

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

how to show that $S_7$ has no sub group of order 11

Is it a proof by contradiction, whereby, let H be the subgroup of order 11,
assume H is a subset of subset of $S_7$, then by lagrange's theorem we state it is not a subset since [...]

Comment: Your final sentence is missing words, no? S7 is the group of the permutations of a set of $7$ elements right?

Answer (score 4):

Contradiction would work here.  Suppose $H \leq S_7$ has order $11$.  By Lagrange's theorem, $11 = |H| \mid |S_7| = 7!$, which is impossible.  Hence, no such $H$ exists.

Answer (score 3):

You've got the right idea, but need to flesh it out and arrive at a contradiction.

Assume there exists an $\,H \leq S_7\,$ with $\,|H| = 11$.

Then by Lagrange's theorem (the order of a subgroup of a finite group divides the order of the group), we have that $\,11\,$ divides $\,|S_7| = 7! = 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1.$

But as we see, that's impossible: $\;11\,{\large \not\mid}\,7!$.

Therefore, no such subgroup $H$ exists.

Comment: Thanks! I've been getting my share of $0\times$ TU's!

Comment: I am intimately familiar with that myself! :-)

Comment: This needs an smaLl code using GAP. @amWhy